# How to find and copy files to folder in bash script

Tags: bash, scripts

In folder I have text files. I want to find them and copy to created folder. Everything works correctly. The code creates a folder and copy files, but console displays:

```
cp: './02_2017/lks07.txt' and '02_2017/lks07.txt' are the same file
```

02_2017 is created folder.

Something is wrong in code but I don't know what

This is the code:

```
date1=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d' -d "-0 month -$(($(date +%d)-1)) days")
date2=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d' -d "-$(date +%d) days +1 month")
date=$(date +'%m_%Y')
mkdir -m 777 $date
find ./ -type f -name '*.txt' -newermt $date1 ! -newermt $date2 -exec cp {} $date \;
```

Can someone please help me whit this ?

Comment: I solved the problem, just added -maxdepth 1 switch to find command.

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs because `find` will look for files sequentially. For example, consider this directory layout:

```
$ tree
.
├── 02_2017
│   └── foo.txt
└── bar.txt
```

When you run your `find` command, it will first find any matching files in the top level directory, so it finds `bar.txt` and moves it into `02_2017`. Then, it will go into `02_2017` and look for files there. There is now a `02_2017/bar.txt` file, so it tries to copy it to itself, fails, and prints that error message.

This is not really a problem. Your script is working fine and is doing its job correctly. You can safely ignore the error.

If it really bothers you, you can fix by adding `-maxdepth 1` to your `find` command so it doesn't descend into subdirectories:

```
find ./ -type f -name '*.txt' -newermt $date1 ! -newermt $date2 -exec cp {} $date \;
```

Or, even better, by excluding the target directory from find's search path:

```
find ./ -type f -not -path './02_2017/*' -name '*.txt' -newermt $date1 ! -newermt $date2 -exec cp {} $date \;
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to accomplish the same task and I received the same error some time ago. The idea was to find all files that were recently modified in a period and back them up separately. Although it is worth mentioning that despite the error from cp the files were being copied. Still I did not like to have an error in the script so I adjusted like this:

```
find /mnt/net_shares/common/ -type f -mtime -15 >> /tmp/common_mod15.$$.txt
```

This will find all files modified the past 15 days and create a list of them in a text file. The $$ operator is the process ID of the script running. This ensures if I have overlapping processes they will not use the same file, makes it unique to the process ID.

```
rsync -azv --files-from=/tmp/common_mod15.$$.txt / /mnt/hd2/backups/local/mod15/common/
```

The second step is to use rsync instead of cp. You can define a text list with `--files-from` switch, and also it will compare files and only copy what has been modified from the files in my backup location. Whereas `cp` would copy and replace everything.

Note that the 'extra' slash in `/tmp/common_mod15.$$.txt **/** /mnt...` is not a typo but I do not remember exactly why I needed it. Had to do with relative vs absolute path. Depending on your generated list you might need it, you might not. But I see that you are working with relative paths also (./ operator) so probably you do need it.

Goes without say that to test it in terminal you need to get rid of the `$$` operator. It only belongs in a script which creates a process ID. Also remember to delete your temporary created file to keep a clean `/tmp` folder.